# Why does my Website looks responsive on resized desktop window, android tablet, but looks bad on small android phone?

Tags: mobile, responsive

My site look good on desktop, when window is resized it is responsive, also when i open it on Android Tab, but when I open it with any Android mobile phone it look bad. I think it does not load my Jquery / JS file. Everything is good CSS wise.

Comment: How on earth could we possibly know without a link to the site?

Comment: Sorry I should have posted more information. :( I figured it out though.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in my main.js file, one of the jquery plugins is not loading on mobile phone so it caused whole program to crash.